# Select data from a right unknown table, how to?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, a user-table and two user-type tables. The user-type tables have a field UserId so they can be linked. The question/problem now is that I have an entry from the user-table. What is the best way to get the data from the right table?

Is it correct to use 2 right joins or can this be done more elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but I'd use LEFT OUTER JOIN.  That is, you want the row from UserTable, and then possibly a row from the appropriate UserType table, if such a row exists.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT ...
FROM UserTable u
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserType1 t1 ON u.userid = t1.userid
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserType2 t2 ON u.userid = t2.userid
```

Presumably at most one of the user-type tables has an entry.  So either t1.* or t2.* will be a single row of all NULLs, and you won't get multiple rows due to Cartesian product.

Comment: Okay, does this bring performance issues to the table when operating on a large scale or is this a robust, fast query? There is always a right-table result.

Comment: That depends on the indexes you've defined in the UserType tables, and which columns you're fetching from them in this query.  If you can get the query to be an index-only query ("Using index" appears in the EXPLAIN report), then it'll be fine.

Comment: In both usertype tables there is an index on UserId, so I guess I'm good. Thanks! +1 and accepted. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `LEFT JOIN`, there's also the `UNION` which needs some more work to show the different columns that the 2 tables might have:

```
    SELECT u.*
         , t1.colA, t1.colB, ..., t1.colZ    --- columns in both tables 1 and 2
         , t1.col_1a, t1.col_1b, t1.col_1c   --- columns in table 1 only 
         , NULL AS col_2a                    --- columns in table 2 only 
         , NULL AS col_2b
    FROM UserTable u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN UserType1 t1 ON u.userid = t1.userid
  UNION ALL
    SELECT u.*
         , t2.colA,   t2.colB,   t2.colC     --- columns in both tables 1 and 2
         , NULL AS col_1a                    --- columns in table 1 only 
         , NULL AS col_1b
         , NULL AS col_1c
         , t2.col_1a, t2.col_1b              --- columns in table 2 only 
    FROM UserTable u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN UserType2 t2 ON u.userid = t2.userid
```